# get parameter from a class search

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Say I have this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <div class="main" data-id="thisID">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the parameter result inside data-id if I do a class search?

```
var el = $('#container');
var row = el.find(".main");
```

Then after this, not sure how to use "row" to get the string id from data-id.

Comment: `row.data('id')` will give you the value of `data-id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery `.data()` or `Element.dataset`

```
var el = $('#container');
var row = el.find(".main");
var id = row.data("id");
```

```
var el = $('#container');
var row = el.find(".main");
var id = row[0].dataset.id;
```

Comment: this didn't get the data-id string, data-id is a parameter name

Comment: @Keith _"this didn't get the data-id string, data-id is a parameter name"_ Not certain what you mean? Are you trying to get the name of the `data-*` attribute at the element?

Comment: data-id is an attribute that I use. I need to grab that string attribute based on the class "main". There are other attributes within that same class so pulling "id" doesn't pull anything

Comment: @Keith _"There are other attributes within that same class so pulling "id" doesn't pull anything"_ Is actual `html` different from `html` at Question? Are you trying to get the name or the value of the `data-*` attribute? Or, are you trying to select the element using the `data-*` attribute?

Comment: i'm trying to get the value of the data-id attribute

Comment: @Keith _"i'm trying to get the value of the data-id attribute"_ See `console` at https://jsfiddle.net/u8umqzpr/

Comment: i found what i was doing wrong. I misunderstood at first. Thanks for the help!